# How to test a mock interaction that it's inside rxjava map/flapmap

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, rx-java

I'm trying to test this code with mockito.

```
public class Repository {
...
    @Override
    public Observable<Data> getCurrentData() {
        return api.getData()
                .map(entityMapper::transform);
    }
}
```

And I would like to test the entityMapper interaction. Here my test scenery:

```
@Test
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun getData() {
    //given
    whenever(api.getData).thenReturn(Observable.just(Data()))
    //when
    debitCardRepo.getCurrentData
    //then
    verify(api).getData
    //TODO verify entityMapper interaction 
}
```

If I try `verify(entityMapper).transform(anyOrNull<>())`, I will get `Wanted but not invoked:`
Does anyone knows how to test an mock interaction inside a map/flapmap?

Comment: What will the `api.getData()` returns? You should return some valid data instead of  `Observable.just(Data())`

Comment: it returns an Observable of data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone knows how to test an mock interaction inside a map/flapmap?

Assuming the rest of your class looks like this:

```
public class Repository {

    private final EntityMapper

    public Repository(EntityMapper entityMapper) {
        this.entityMapper = entityMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Data> getCurrentData() {
        return api.getData()
                .map(entityMapper::transform);
    }
}
```

Then stubbing a behaviour on a mocked `EntityMapper` will work if you wait for the `Observable` to complete:

```
@Test
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun testGetData() {
    //given
    val data = Data()
    whenever(api.getData).thenReturn(Observable.just(data))
    //when
    repository.getCurrentData().blockingGet()
    //then
    verify(entityMapper).transform(any())
}
```

Note the call to `blockingGet()` - otherwise it is possible for the test to complete before the mapping has occurred. You should also look at the `Observable#test()` method to see better options here.

However in this case since the repository does very little apart from delegating to the API and calling the `EntityMapper` and this seems to be the main interaction you are interested in, why not test `EntityMapper` separately?

If you write a separate test for `EntityMapper` then you can use a black-box test (simply call `transform` on your data and see if the transformation matches your expectations). This kind of test is much more stable and valuable than white-box testing with `verify` which can sometimes degenerate into tests that are a reverse implementation of system under test.

Comment: I agree that I should test the mapper separately. I don't want to test the mapper itself, but make sure that the mapper is called in this repository (just testing the mock interaction)

Comment: is it a bad practice?

Comment: In general it's better to write tests that aren't so tied to a particular implementation. The fact that `map` is called is evident from the source code The suggestion in the other answer to write a black box test against the output is a good one.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't subscribe.

`debitCardRepo.getCurrentData` will just return an `Observable` but not actually really do anything.

```
@Test
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun getData() {
    //given
    whenever(api.getData).thenReturn(Observable.just(Data()))
    //when
    debitCardRepo.getCurrentData.subscribe()
    //then
    verify(api).getData 
}
```

regardless, this isn't a great test, as you're testing a side effect happens. some map/transform function is called. Why don't you test the output?

```
@Test
@Throws(Exception::class)
fun getData() {
    //given
    val data = Data()
    whenever(api.getData).thenReturn(Observable.just(data))
    //when
    val transformedData = debitCardRepo.getCurrentData.blockingGet()
    //then
    assertEquals(data, transformedData)
}
```

This is a more meaningful test. Simple refactors won't break this test unless the change the behavior of the class.